# Which waves or lights or systems can detect humans behind walls

Tags: waves

I'm looking for a system to detect people who are located behind a wall. I don't know anything about science (except high school science) so any help works

Comment: Active or passive? THz sensors are the former

Answer (score 2):

There are devices using radio frequencies, e.g., Wi-Fi, for seeing inside or behind walls. Check, e.g., Walabot (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-83Ou9QciA , https://walabot.com/).